# VB6 dll working in VB6 application, not in ASP

Tags: dll, com, vb6, vbscript, asp-classic

I'm working on an old project in asp
I've never worked with vb6 or asp before I am a .net developer

anyway

I made a .net dll and changed some compile options to make it work with vb6
the code doesnt matter

I made a "wrapper kinda" dll in vb6

```
Public Function EncryptWrapper(ByVal parameterstring As String, ByVal isShaIn As String, ByVal HashType As String) As String
    Dim o
    Set o = CreateObject("SHA1Module.Conversion")
    EncryptWrapper = CStr(o.EncryptToSHA1(CStr(parameterstring), CBool(isShaIn), CLng(HashType)))
End Function
```

and a form in vb6 that calls it

```
    Private Sub Command1_Click()
    Dim message
    Dim myObject
    Set myObject = CreateObject("SHAModuleWrapper.Encryption")
    message = myObject.EncryptWrapper(txtIn.Text, "1", "2")
    Set myObject = Nothing
    txtOut.Text = message
End Sub
```

this works perfectly

now in asp I try calling that dll and I get an error

```
<%  Dim strMessage 
    Dim message
    strMessage = "hello"
    Dim myObject
    Set myObject = Server.CreateObject("SHAModuleWrapper.Encryption")
        message = myObject.EncryptWrapper("testdagtestdagtest", "1", "0")
    Response.Write(message)
%>
```

this is the error message

SHAModuleWrapper error '800a0005'

Invalid procedure call or argument

/asptest/Default.asp, line 15

It's not the parameters or the output
it's this part that is causing the trouble

```
**Dim o
Set o = CreateObject("SHA1Module.Conversion")
EncryptWrapper = CStr(o.EncryptToSHA1(CStr(parameterstring), CBool(isShaIn), CLng(HashType)))**
```

Does anybody have an idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lot of frustration and batch files later I found the solution.
I needed to create a strong name for my assembly and register it in the GAC

This is a good step by step tutorial on how to solve this issue
[Tutorial](http://weblogs.asp.net/dneimke/archive/2004/01/31/65330.aspx)

these 2 steps helped me

**8) Generate a public/private key pair**

```
sn -k MarkItUp.key
```

**9) Add the attribute to my assembly for registering it:**

```
<Assembly: AssemblyKeyFile("C:\MarkItUp.key")>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim o 
Dim message
Dim myObject
```

These lines are cause for concern. These will be a variant as they are not a defined type.

`Option Explicit` is your friend in VB6 - use it always!

Have a look at this link: [Avoid program bugs in VB6 with the Option Explicit statement](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/avoid-program-bugs-in-vb6-with-the-option-explicit-statement/5798636) for more information.

Comment: thanks for the interesting link, I'm not used to working vb or even vb.net. The reason I wrote this sloppy code is because intellisense in vb6 is not as pro as I'm used to in vs2010/vs2008. I guess I took the easy way out :).

Answer (score 0):

in your bad code you have
`Set o = CreateObject("SHA1Module.Conversion")`
should it be
`Set o = CreateObject("SHA1Module.Encryption")`

Comment: My question might seem a litle confusing. But SHA1Module.Conversion is the .net class and SHAModuleWrapper.Encrypten is the vb6 class (the wrapper). The only reason I tried a wrapper is because someone at the office thought this might work.

Answer (score 0):

Check that IUSR_*Machine* has permission to execute your dlls.